# Does your drawing partner see trashed drawings?

Tags: draw-something

In Draw Something if you completely mess up a drawing you can press the Trash button to start again. Will your drawing partner see the drawings that you trash, or will they only see the final version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe they get to view the entire process of your drawing, including if you trash midway and start over. If you think of it as a recording of your process, then it makes sense that they would see that part.

Comment: They see the wipe animation just like you do.

Comment: I can confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is just like a movie to watch the other drawing :)

Answer (score 0):

They do see your trashed drawings. In fact I often make use of this. For example I had Garlic as a word the other day... so I drew Garfield and a "-", then deleted. Then drew a field and deleted, and then drew a + and a tongue licking.